# How to add new Field to sharepoint list with SpServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

Hi i'm trying to create a sharepoint list with SPServices and I've got the create part working.

next i need to add new columns either during the creation or after. However I cant get the add new fileds to work.

```
var fieldsNew = "<Fields><Method ID='1'><Field Type='Text' List='{7B4575c08a-0a82-4ed6-a367-102fa380aedf}' ShowField='ID' DisplayName='MatchedEquipmentRecord'></Field></Method></Fields>";



$().SPServices({
  operation: "UpdateList",
  listName: "myfirstList",
  listProperties:"",
  updateFields: "",
  newFields: fieldsNew,
  deleteFields: "",
  listVersion: "",
  async: false,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status){
      alert(xData.status);
      alert(xData.responseText);  
  }
});
```

i'm getting a 200 code back from the alert(xData.status); which as far as i'm awere is a sucssess code but when i look at the list it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $().SPServices({  
        operation: "AddList",  
        async: false,  
        listName: "myfirstList",  
        description: "....",  
        templateID: "100",  
        completefunc: function(xData, Status)   
      {  
            if (xData.status == 200)   
            {  
                alert(strListName + ' List created successfully');  
            } else  
            {  
                alert(xData.status);  
                alert(xData.responseText);  
            }  
        }  
    });  


var fieldsToUpdate = '<Fields>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="1"><Field Type="Text" Name="Application Family" DisplayName="Applicationfamily"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="2"><Field Type="Text" Name="Manufacturer" DisplayName="Manufacturer"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="3"><Field Type="Text" Name="Description" DisplayName="Description"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="4"><Field Type="Text" Name="Software Tag" DisplayName="TAG"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="5"><Field Type="Text" Name="software Type" DisplayName="SoftwareClass"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '<Method ID="6"><Field Type="Text" Name="Status" DisplayName="Status"><Default></Default></Field></Method>';
    fieldsToUpdate += '</Fields>';





 $().SPServices({
      operation: "UpdateList",
      listName: "myfirstList",
      listProperties:"",
      updateFields: "",
      newFields: fieldsToUpdate,
      deleteFields: "",
      listVersion: "",
      async: false,
      completefunc: function (xData, Status){
          alert(xData.status);

      }
    });
```

I fixed it now works fine